# How can I print starting offset of each partition of Kafka topic from which Flink has started reading?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to print the starting offset of each partition of the Kafka topic from which Flink has started reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `KafkaDeserializationSchema` to handle deserialization with your `FlinkKafkaConsumer`, the `deserialize` method is passed a `ConsumerRecord`, which includes the partition and offset. You could print or log that the first time the method is called.